# Nuget 2.7: "an error occurred while processing this request"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

Since I while me and everbody in my team get this error message when we try to check for nuget package updates:

> An error occurred while processing this request.

This only happens if I check in individual projects. It works if I do it on a solution level.

I updated to nuget 2.7.40808.167

> Settings:
>   nuget.org
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

I've already tried to deinstall and install it again. But nothing.
It also happens on my laptop at home (but with the same project).

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the requests?

Comment: Not really getting anything. If I search for a package, then I get results on the Update section. Otherwise just the error message.

Comment: Can't be that my whole team has this issue and nobody else???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too am having the same issue with Nuget 2.7. As a workaround I am currently utilizing the Package Manager Console. The command `Get-Package -updates` will list all available updates for a project:

[image: example of Get-Package -updates]

From there you can use the `Update-Package` cmdlet to update specific packages.

Comment: Im getting some weird results like this. It lists packages that I have long uninstalled and are def. not part of the project anymore.

Comment: @Remy From Tools > Options > Package Manager I checked "Allow NuGet to download missing pacakge" and also checked "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio". After doing so a bunch of missing package pieces were downloaded. After the missing files were downloaded I was able to update packages via the GUI. Are your options configured similarly?

Comment: Yes, we used that to keep the team in sync. Maybe I have to setup all the nuget stuff new.